# CGContextDraw ... Web?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Does anybody know if it is possible to use Quartz 2d to something like a CGContextDraw(Web) ?
To basically draw the content of a webpage .

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.

But you can use `-[CALayer renderInContext:]` to make a `UIWebView` draw into a `CGContextRef`.